# Nodemailer body with qrcode image

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm creating the server with express and want to send mail with QRcode inside the body

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var nodeMailer = require('nodemailer');
var sql = require("mssql");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var QRCode = require('qrcode')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

app.post('/send-email', function (req, res) {
        QRCode.toDataURL('data invoice untuk di kirim melalui email', function (err, url) {
            let data = url.replace(/.*,/,'')
            var img = new Buffer(data,'base64')

        })
          let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
              host: 'test',
              port: 587,
              secure: false,
              auth: {
                  user: 'tes',
                  pass: 'password'
              }
          });
          let mailOptions = {
              from: 'test', // sender address
              to: 'test', // list of receivers
              subject: 'Test Email Node JS', // Subject line
              text: 'Halo ini dari node js', // plain text body
              html: 'Halo ini barcodenya </br>' + img // html body
          };

          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
              if (error) {
                  return console.log(error);
              }
              //console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
                  res.render('index');
              });
      });
```

I get an error that `img` is not defined.

Variable `img` is what the qr code, and for the string it will get the string from SQL query.

Any source for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `QRCode.toDataURL` is a asynchronous function but your trying to use as synchronously. Use Promises and Async/Await in place of callback [function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode#es6es7).
2. Your sending a image as buffer but its need to be in `base64` with `image tag`

Here are the code snippet changes,

```
...

app.post('/send-email', async function (req, res) {

    let img = await QRCode.toDataURL('data invoice untuk di kirim melalui email');

    let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
        host: 'test',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'tes',
            pass: 'password'
        }
    });
    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'test', // sender address
        to: 'test', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Test Email Node JS', // Subject line
        text: 'Halo ini dari node js', // plain text body
        html: 'Halo ini barcodenya </br> <img src="' + img + '">' // html body
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        //console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
        res.render('index');
    });
});

...
```

Answer (score 1):

in the `mailOptions` you need to add the `attachDataUrls` on true

```
let mailOptions = {
    from: 'test', // sender address
    to: 'test', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Test Email Node JS', // Subject line
    text: 'Halo ini dari node js', // plain text body
    attachDataUrls: true,//to accept base64 content in messsage
    html: 'Halo ini barcodenya </br> <img src="' + img + '">' // html body
};
```

Comment: Docs mention this option, but Typescript `@types` package does not. Not sure can I use it...

Answer (score 0):

This is the key!!

attachDataUrls: true, //to accept base64 content in messsage